# Tensorflow speech_commands error: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

I'm trying to run the [Speech_Commands](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/tutorials/audio_recognition) example with custom data on a Digital Ocean ML droplet. I've changed the word list to only include two of the original ones and one of my own. I've also reduced the steps to only 700. After training I ran the `freeze.py` file with the '--start_checkpoint' and the '-output_file' parameters I got the following error:

```
2018-05-13 14:22:14.599027: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:140] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2 FMA
2018-05-13 14:22:15.263582: W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:1318] OP_REQUIRES failed at save_restore_tensor.cc:170 : Not found: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1322, in _do_call
    return fn(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1307, in _run_fn
    options, feed_dict, fetch_list, target_list, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for 
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "freeze.py", line 180, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "freeze.py", line 117, in main
    models.load_variables_from_checkpoint(sess, FLAGS.start_checkpoint)
  File "/root/models.py", line 123, in load_variables_from_checkpoint
    saver.restore(sess, start_checkpoint)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1802, in restore
    {self.saver_def.filename_tensor_name: save_path})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 900, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1135, in _run
    feed_dict_tensor, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1316, in _do_run
    run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1335, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for 
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]

Caused by op 'save/RestoreV2', defined at:
  File "freeze.py", line 180, in <module>
    tf.app.run(main=main, argv=[sys.argv[0]] + unparsed)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "freeze.py", line 117, in main
    models.load_variables_from_checkpoint(sess, FLAGS.start_checkpoint)
  File "/root/models.py", line 122, in load_variables_from_checkpoint
    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.global_variables())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1338, in __init__
    self.build()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1347, in build
    self._build(self._filename, build_save=True, build_restore=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 1384, in _build
    build_save=build_save, build_restore=build_restore)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 835, in _build_internal
    restore_sequentially, reshape)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 472, in _AddRestoreOps
    restore_sequentially)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/saver.py", line 886, in bulk_restore
    return io_ops.restore_v2(filename_tensor, names, slices, dtypes)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_io_ops.py", line 1463, in restore_v2
    shape_and_slices=shape_and_slices, dtypes=dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

NotFoundError (see above for traceback): Unsuccessful TensorSliceReader constructor: Failed to find any matching files for 
     [[Node: save/RestoreV2 = RestoreV2[dtypes=[DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT, DT_FLOAT], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](_arg_save/Const_0_0, save/RestoreV2/tensor_names, save/RestoreV2/shape_and_slices)]]
```

Any idea what caused this and how to fix it? I'm assuming that the code from the example works because I tried this with the defaults and it worked then.

Comment: So, it turns out that I had forgotten to change the wanted words parameter in the freeze.py file.

Answer (score 1):

So, it turns out that I had forgotten to change the wanted words parameter in the freeze.py file.